# How to maintain an equal height of main slide and the vertical slides with the arrows(prev and next) in Vertical slider syncing in slick slider?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slick.js

I'm implementing a vertical slider like this

```
<div class="vertical-slider col-md-7 ga-vertical-gallery" id="slider">
<section class="services-slider">
   <div class="nav-container">
   <i class="fa fa-angle-up next">^</i>
    <div class="slider-nav">
      <div>
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x600">
      </div>
      <div>
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x600/000080">
      </div>
      <div>
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x600/fff">
      </div>
      <div>
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x600/sss">
      </div>
      <div>
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x600/FF33F0">
      </div>
      <div>
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x600/F3FF33">
      </div>
    </div>
    <i class="fa fa-angle-down prev ">&#8964;</i>
  </div>
  <div class="main-container">
    <div class="slider slider-main">
      <div>
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x600">
      </div>
      <div>
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x600/000080">
      </div>
      <div>
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x600/fff">
      </div>
      <div>
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x600/sss">
      </div>
      <div>
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x600/FF33F0">
      </div>
      <div>
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x600/F3FF33">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</section>
</div>
```

The keyparts of the  code is here(there is no font awesome link=>so no icons )https://codepen.io/ydev/pen/KOVYrP

I always want at max 5 images for the nav slider, added to that  I want the main image slider  height and the height of the arrows(prev, next) and the vertical thumbnail images to look the same  like this(here 6 images at the nav  slider but I want just 5 images.)
[image]

I also want the distance between the nav slides and the arrows to look the same. I'm open to the idea of changing my heights. Any insights on how to tackle this?

Answer (score 0):

You can select max show images in slick setting like this.

```
$('.slider-main').slick({
        slidesToShow: 1,
        arrows: false,
        asNavFor: '.slider-nav',
        vertical: true,
        autoplay: false,
        verticalSwiping: true,
        centerMode: false
      });
```

If you need anything else you can check official documentation

[Here](https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/)

Or write ask me

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I know the option  slidesToShow. What I meant was that I always want at max 5 images for the nav slider and  the main image slider height and the height of the arrows and the vertical thumbnail images to look the same at the same time(like the image i attached)

Comment: you can share your css and js

Comment: I posted it in the question. please check this link https://codepen.io/ydev/pen/KOVYrP

Comment: i had seen it and its valid i need to see your write code

Comment: I wrote the same code as the one that I wrote in the codepen but I was outputting the Html in a loop via PHP. I changed the images to my company-specific images

Comment: i changed the arrows with prev and next here https://codepen.io/ydev/pen/KOVYrP , you can see that the distance between the first slide, next and the distance between the last slide, prev is not the same. And all of them together is  not having the same height as the main slider slide